# What is the dimension of the span over $\mathbb{F}$ of permutation matrices on $n$ elements if $char(\mathbb{F})$ divides $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, representation-theory, permutation-matrices

I'm trying to generalize Birkhoff's theorem and prove that over any field $\mathbb{F}$ any matrix whose sum of rows and columns is equal to some constant, is a linear combination of permutation matrices.

For fields where the characteristic $p$ does not divide $n$, we can use a dimensional argument: compare the dimension over $\mathbb{F}$ of the span of all permutation matrices on $n$ points with the algebra $Mat_{n-1}(\mathbb{F})\oplus \mathbb{F}$. These algebras are isomorphic as it is sufficient for $p$ to not be a factor of $n$ so that it the representation decomposes into the direct sum of the trivial and the permutation representation. This does not work otherwise. Any hints?

Comment: Any matrix of the form $E_{11} + E_{jv} - E_{1v} - E_{j1}$ (with $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $1 \leq v \leq n$) is a linear combination of permutation matrices (indeed, it is a difference of two permutation matrices, whose corresponding permutations differ by a single transposition). By adding an appropriate linear combination of such matrices to your matrix, you can easily get it to a form where all entries outside of the first row and the first column are $0$. But the sums of rows and columns do not change when you do this. So if they were constant at first, they still equal that constant. ...

Comment: ... This will tell you rather quickly that the new matrix has only $2n-1$ potentially nonzero entries, with $2n-2$ of them being equal. You can easily write that matrix as a linear combination of permutation matrices (namely, the ones corresponding to the identity permutation and to the transpositions $\left(1,2\right), \left(1,3\right), \ldots, \left(1,n\right)$.

Comment: As for your representation argument, I'm not sure what you're trying to use here. Representations of what?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the standard representation $S_n$. I edited the question and it seems a bit unclear now. Will give a further edit. Still need to digest your argument but thanks for it in advance.